# Calculate instantaneous rate of change for town population

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The population of town is modelled by $P(t)= 6t^2 + 110t + 3000$ where $P$ is population and $t$ is number of years since $1990$.

**Find $P(15)$ and explain meaning of that term.** 
For this I can put $t=15$ in above equation and calculate value. But what's the meaning of that term $P(15)$?

**Estimate the rate at which the population is changing in 2005.** Is it asking to calculate the instantaneous rate of change? For eg. Can I calculate $(P(x2)-P(x1))/x2-x1$ for$2005 \leq t \leq 2006$, $2005 \leq t \leq 2005.5 ... 2005   \leq t <= 2005.01$?

Comment: Yes, take P(t) and set $t = 15$ to obtain $P(15)$. This value is the population in 15 years, or the population in $2005$.

Comment: It wants the instantaneous rate of change when $t = 15$ since that corresponds to $2005$. Since you put "derivatives" in the tags, do you know calculus? Taking the derivative would be the far superior method.

Comment: I was not sure to put the derivatives. I'm relatively new to this forum. Please update question if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** $P(15)=6\cdot15^2 + 110\cdot 15 + 3000 = 3000 + 3000 = 6000$.
So 15 years after 1990 $\rightarrow$ in 2005, the population is composed of 6000 people !

**2)** For a function, the instantaneous rate of change at a point is the same as the slope of the tangent line.
Let's compute the slope of P : $$\frac{\mathrm{d}P }{\mathrm{d} t}=12t+110$$
So at $t=15 \  (\leftrightarrow2005)$, we have $12\cdot15 +110 =290 $
$$\\$$
$$In \ \  other \ \ words : $$
To compute the average change of population at $t=15$ , we simply choose another point $t$ and so the Average Rate of Change will be : $$\frac{change \ of \ population}{time \  passed} = \frac{P(t)-P(15)}{t-15}   
=\frac{6t^2+110t+3000 - 6000}{t-15}=\frac{6t^2+110t-3000}{t-15}$$

Now we have the average rate of change at $t=15$.

To have the instantaneous rate of change at $t=15$, we will choose some values of $t$ that will get **closer and closer** to $15$ on both sides $\rightarrow t=14.99, t=15.01 \ etc..$

After computing that in Maple, you will see that we are getting closer and closer of 290 ! This means that in 2005, the population increased by 290 people.

[image: Evolution of the Rate of Change]

Hope this helps !

Comment: How do you get 12t+110?

Comment: This is the concept of "derivative". It seems that you don't have study this yet so I will not develop but you need to understand how I found the instantaneous rate of change using the average rate of change !